# custom fonts failing to load during unit tests after android gradle plugin upgrade

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I'm writing unit tests (using `robolectric 3.1`) for company's project. In a recent commit, `android gradle plugin` version was updated from `2.1.0` to `2.2.3`.
This change caused tests to fail whenever a test is calling code that loads custom fonts.

Changing plugin version back to `2.1.0` fixes the issue, but I've been told that version change is required and has to stay. Anyway, our CI build environment has no problem with tests, so it seems that the issue occurs only for my local build.

I've updated JRE and SDK, both 1.8 (and set JAVA_HOME to updated JDK directory), and Android Studio, to no avail. Assets directory is correctly placed under 'main', not 'res' directory (fonts are in app/src/main/assets/fonts/).
Cleaning the project and restarting IDE with cache invalidation also didn't help.

Issue persist after turning Instant Run off, so it's not the one described here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213454

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        (...)
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    (...)
}
```

Example code using custom fonts (layout):

```
<com.example.CustomFontTextView
                (...)
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                custom:customFont="@string/custom_font_path"/>
```

Custom font text view:

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomFontTextView(final Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomFontTextView (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

        if(!isInEditMode()){
            initTextView(context, attrs);
        }
    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if(!isInEditMode()){
            initTextView(context, attrs);
        }
    }

    private void initTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs){

        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFontView);
        String customFont = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomFontView_customFont);
        setText(getText());
        if(customFont!=null){
            Typeface tf = getTypeface(context, customFont);
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
        attributes.recycle();
    }

    private Typeface getTypeface(final Context context, final String customFontPath) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontPath);
    }

    public void setTypeFace(Context con, String font){
        if(font != null && con != null){
            Typeface tf = getTypeface(con, font);
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomFontView">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

font paths are being kept in strings:

```
<string name="custom_font_path">fonts/CustomFont.ttf</string>
```

Exception (happening during layout inflation):

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build\intermediates\res\merged\mock\debug\layout\layout.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class <unknown>
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font not found at [build\intermediates\bundles\mock\debug\assets\fonts\CustomFont.ttf]
```

What is causing font loading to fail ? Is Robolectric to blame ?

Comment: Font not found at [build\intermediates\bundles\mock\debug\assets\fonts\CustomFont.ttf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Robolectric indeed

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2647

Android gradle plugin internal implementation changed in 2.2 but Robolectric 3.1 is still based on old implemetation. It's fixed in Robolectric 3.2. Besides of robolectric upgrade, solution suggested on github by otbinary also works like a charm:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def productFlavor = "${variant.productFlavors[0].name.capitalize()}"
    def buildType = "${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}"
    tasks["compile${productFlavor}${buildType}UnitTestSources"].dependsOn(tasks["merge${productFlavor}${buildType}Assets"])
}
This creates a dependency for all compile*UnitTestSources Gradle tasks on the corresponding merge*Assets tasks. The merge tasks copy all assets to app/build/intermediates/assets, where Robolectric finds them.
```